# Write a formula in cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I tried writing the below formula in vba. It keeps throwing me an error. When I change the formula to contain just INDEX then it seems to work . Can someone explain why

Thank you

```
Worksheet.Range("W2").Formula = "=INDEX('tilkoding'!E1:F32;MATCH(J2;'tilkoding'!E1:E32;0);2)"
```

Comment: Change the `;` to `,`.

Comment: When adding a formula via VBA you use the "USA" list separator (comma).  If you want to use your local separator then you can use `.FormulaLocal`